# Is there is way to use only few of vim command in vscode

Tags: vim, plugins, visual-studio-code, insert, command

I am on the window system and using vscode. I am trying to find vim insert mode alternative in vscode.

Like : when we press "i" in vim  it goes to "insert mode" and allow to edit other wise don`t.  the same functionality i want in vscode.

Comment: VS Code is in "insert mode" by default...

Comment: yes i know.  the think i am trying to ask is that, when we press "i"  vim goes to "edit mode" and allow to edit file , other wise vim don`t  allow .  the same functionality i want in my vscode when i press a key then it goes to edit mode and allow to edit file other wise not.

Answer (score 0):

Natively, there is no way, but thanks to the extensive plugin system you can easily accomplish this. [VSCodeVim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) is a great example.

Comment: i try this but does`t achieve the success. can you ex-plane how ..?

Comment: Sure, it is really simple. Open VSCode, open the extension tab (its the bottom icon on the left most pane). In the search pane type 'vim'. Install plugin named 'Vim'. After installation completes, restart VSCode. Now vim insert mode should work as it usually does.